# Splitting the shared module into multiple child modules

Tags: javascript, angular

Inside of my `SharedModule` I want to split up related pieces of code into multiple child modules. When I do that however, I lose the common imports from the shared module. For example, I import the `FormsModule` before my `SharedChildModule`, but when I try to use ngModel inside my `SharedChildModule` it tells me that `ngModel` isn't available. Is it possible to have child modules inside the shared module and also to have those modules inherit the modules from the `SharedModule`?

When I include the components and directives from `ChildSharedModule` directly in the `SharedModule` I have no issues. It is only when I attempt to move those into a child module and then import the whole module into `SharedModule` that I get the errors.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,

    ChildSharedModule
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,

    ChildSharedModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChildValidatorDirective,
    ChildControlComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    ChildValidatorDirective,
    ChildControlComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedChildModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not push *down* dependencies of modules, but you can *export* modules upwards.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    exports: [
        ChildSharedModule
    ],
    imports: [
        ChildSharedModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ChildValidatorDirective,
        ChildControlComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        ChildValidatorDirective,
        ChildControlComponent,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ]
})
export class SharedChildModule {}
```

Now `SharedModule` will import `SharedChildModule` and will receive everything that is *exported* by that child module. Since `SharedModule` is also exporting `SharedChildModule` then *parents* who import it will also receive `CommonModule` and `FormsModule`.

You are basically *breaking* tree shaking here, and making unit testing very difficult.

Angular will no longer be able to drop unused modules, because you are coupling everything together. It will also become difficult to remove `FormsModule` from `SharedChildModule` because you won't know how many parents depend upon it.

You should try to keep your modules as *singular* and *flat* as possible, and have each module import only what it specifically needs.

You can export another module when the consumer doesn't know that other module is a requirement.